# C# ObjectListView - manually set SelectedObject

Tags: c#, object, listviewitem, objectlistview

This code won't set `SelectedObject` in ObjectListView:

```
int ID = 1; // unique

foreach (object o in ObjectListViewInstance.Objects)
{
    if (o.ID == ID)
    {
        this.ObjectListViewInstance.SelectedObject = o;
        break;
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by won't select? It selects but probably doesn't focus the item.

Comment: @EugenePodskal: It won't select item visually. This is summary of `SelectedObject` from documentation: _Gets the model object from the currently selected row, if there is only one row selected. If no row is selected, or more than one is selected, returns null. When setting, this will select the row that is displaying the given model object and focus on it. All other rows are deselected._

Comment: I've tried sample project from http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html and it(`SelectedObject`) more or less worked.

Comment: Are you updating the OLV with a timer?

Answer (score 2):

`ObjectListView` does not know anything about the objects it is handling, so you first have to cast the `ObjectListView.Objects` to the type `myObjectType` you are using. Then you can use some nice LINQ features to find the right object directly, no need to iterate through all objects.
Then finally you can have the `ObjectListView` select the item.

```
int ID = 1; // unique

myObjectType selectItem =
    this.ObjectListViewInstance.Objects.Cast<myObjectType>().FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == ID);

if (selectItem != null) 
{ 
    this.ObjectListViewInstance.SelectObject(selectItem); 
}
```

Please also remember that the `ListView` and `ObjectListView` controls have a `HideSelection` property that by default hides the highlight if the listview does not have the focus.

Comment: You have a small type "selectedItem" should be "selectItem"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean, but `SelectedObject` property works for me. It actually selects the item, but it doesn't highlight it (changes background to another color).

But `ListViewItem.Selected` (`ListViewObject` `Items` are actually plain [ListViewItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem(v=vs.110).aspx)) does it, so [Selected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.selected(v=vs.110).aspx) property is perhaps what you need:

```
int ID = 1; // unique
int index = 0;

foreach (object o in ObjectListViewInstance.Objects)
{
    if (o.ID == ID)
        break;

    index++;
}

this.ObjectListViewInstance.Items[index].Selected = true;
```

If you want to deselect everything else (because it won't remove selection from other items), you can either use `this.ObjectListViewInstance.SelectedObject = this.ObjectListViewInstance.Objects[index]` or just manually deselect them.

Also, you possibly may want to [Focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus(v=vs.110).aspx) your `ObjectListViewInstance` if it is not already focused.

**P.S.:** There may be some native method to find corresponding `ListViewItem` from bound object, but I don't know it. And there may be some gotcha if `ObjectListView` uses tricky virtualization that makes `Items` and `Objects` collections out of sync.

Comment: I tried everything you wrote, but it didn't help. Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: @jirinovo Well, I just don't understand what exactly does not work. With sample app from site it works well enough (SelectedObject marks the item with border, Items[].Selected changes its background) Or do you mean that it does not end up correctly set in control properties?

Comment: Simply the ListViewItem is not focused/selected. I mean the same result as in the case when user clicks on row.

Comment: Maybe something else interferes? Have you tried to compare your code with samples - http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html?

Comment: I'm using `ObjectListView` for longer time and this is a first time I get stucked. Luckily it's not insurmountable problem in my app :)

Comment: @jirinovo: Since you mention focus, you have to select `HideSelection` to false. Otherwise the control will - well, "hide the selection" - when out of focus.

Comment: @EugenePodskal: From the OLV point of view, its bad practice to manually manipulate the underlying `Items`. I believe it has to do with the sorting/indexing mechanisms. It is not guaranteed that the index in `Items` matches the display index or index after sorting, grouping etc.

Comment: @Rev1.0 I have already mentioned it in P.S., but thanks nonetheless, because it is a first time I ever seen this control.

Comment: @EugenePodskal: Oh sorry, I overlooked that one.